# How to import promised based variable to use in another module (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, module, fetch, es6-promise

how to import a value of the promised based function to another module?

```
// index.js file:

import test from "./test";
console.log(test) // expected result should be "delectus aut autem" - now getting Promise object


// test.js file:

var test = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(function (data) {
    return data.title
  });

export default test
```

working example:
https://js-njm471.stackblitz.io

Comment: It is likely just a matter of handling the promise using `then`. E.g., `test.then(data => { console.log(data) })`

Comment: Great, I will formalize as an answer if you wouldn't mind upvoting/accepting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `test` is a promise, you simply have to handle it as such after you import it.

```
test.then(data => { 
    console.log(data);
});
```